DAX: Exclude previously iterated rows from filter context
I want to evaluate CONTAINS only within the context of a subset of rows based on one column (gameid).
I have been passing incorrect filters into CONTAINS, as a result, it evaluates the SWITCH conditions in the context of the entire table, rather than the intended purpose, of only a subset of rows based on the current gameid being iterated.
Hi,
I've been trying to make the code below evaluate the SWITCH conditions only within the context of the current row.
When I pass Test_Table (making the gameid = 1) to CONTAINS, the code works as intended displaying these values in the picture.
But passing Test_Table2, with the intended that the SELECTEDVALUE grabs the current row during the iteration, does not work as intended.
How do I go about properly passing a filter to CONTAINS , so that during the iteration, it only searches the pick columns for the current gameid during the iteration and not the entire table.
Ive attached another picture, displaying the incorrect results when I dont hardcode the filter to gameid = 1.
Edit: PBIX File, With two DAX queries called "Faulty blind pick functionality" and "Intended blind pick functionality"
Edit 2: Providing further context on the dataset. The dataset is based on the Chinese League of Legends pro league, with 17 teams playing 16 best-of-three games against each other.
A GameID represents a single game played.
There is 3888 rows in the main fact table (LPL_Spring_Season_2024), with 12 rows per gameid (324 unique gameids).
Of the 12 rows per gameid, number 1-5 in the participantid column represents players from the blue team of that game and numbers 6-10 represents players from the red team. Number 100 represents blue team and 200 represents red team.
Prior to the game starting, there is a pick phase where each team selects their champion to play, with the order taking place as such:
Blue team (participantid 100): Picks their 1st Champion (1)
Red team (participantid 200): Picks their 1st and 2nd Champion (2)
BT: Picks their 2nd and 3rd Champion (3)
RT: Picks their 3rd and 4th Champion (4)
BT: Picks their 4th and 5th Champion (5)
RT Picks their 5th Champion (6)
The pick columns are only populated, in the rows where the participantid is 100 or 200.
The pick columns searches the champion column and assigns a number based on the pick order above.

DEFINE 
VAR Min_GameID = MIN(LPL_Spring_Season_2024[GameID])
VAR Max_GameID = MAX(LPL_Spring_Season_2024[GameID])
VAR Iterate_GameID = FILTER(
    ALL(LPL_Spring_Season_2024),
    AND ( 
        LPL_Spring_Season_2024[GameID] >= Min_GameID,
        LPL_Spring_Season_2024[GameID] <= Max_GameID
    )
)
VAR  Test_Table = CALCULATETABLE(
    LPL_Spring_Season_2024,
    LPL_Spring_Season_2024[GameID] = Min_GameID
)
VAR Test_Table2 = CALCULATETABLE(
    LPL_Spring_Season_2024,
    LPL_Spring_Season_2024[GameID] = SELECTEDVALUE(LPL_Spring_Season_2024[GameID])
)

VAR Pre_Filt = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    LPL_Spring_Season_2024,
    "Pick Order",
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        CONTAINS(
            Test_Table,
            LPL_Spring_Season_2024[pick1], LPL_Spring_Season_2024[champion] 
        ) && LPL_Spring_Season_2024[participantid] <= 5,
        1,
        CONTAINS(
            Test_Table,
            LPL_Spring_Season_2024[pick2], LPL_Spring_Season_2024[champion] 
        ) && LPL_Spring_Season_2024[participantid] <= 5,
        3,
        CONTAINS(
            Test_Table,
            LPL_Spring_Season_2024[pick3], LPL_Spring_Season_2024[champion] 
        ) && LPL_Spring_Season_2024[participantid] <= 5,
        3,
        CONTAINS(
            Test_Table,
            LPL_Spring_Season_2024[pick4], LPL_Spring_Season_2024[champion] 
        ) && LPL_Spring_Season_2024[participantid] <= 5,
        5,
        CONTAINS(
            Test_Table,
            LPL_Spring_Season_2024[pick5], LPL_Spring_Season_2024[champion] 
        ) && LPL_Spring_Season_2024[participantid] <= 5,
        5,
        CONTAINS(
            Test_Table,  
            LPL_Spring_Season_2024[pick1], LPL_Spring_Season_2024[champion] 
        ) && LPL_Spring_Season_2024[participantid] < 11,
        2,
        CONTAINS(
            Test_Table,  
            LPL_Spring_Season_2024[pick2], LPL_Spring_Season_2024[champion] 
        ) && LPL_Spring_Season_2024[participantid] < 11,
        2,
        CONTAINS(
            Test_Table,  
            LPL_Spring_Season_2024[pick3], LPL_Spring_Season_2024[champion] 
        ) && LPL_Spring_Season_2024[participantid] < 11,        
        4,
        CONTAINS(
            Test_Table,  
            LPL_Spring_Season_2024[pick4], LPL_Spring_Season_2024[champion] 
        ) && LPL_Spring_Season_2024[participantid] < 11,        
        4,      
        CONTAINS(
            Test_Table,  
            LPL_Spring_Season_2024[pick4], LPL_Spring_Season_2024[champion] 
        ) && LPL_Spring_Season_2024[participantid] < 11,        
        4,              
        CONTAINS(
            Test_Table,  
            LPL_Spring_Season_2024[pick5], LPL_Spring_Season_2024[champion] 
        ) && LPL_Spring_Season_2024[participantid] < 11,        
        6,          
BLANK()  
    )
)
EVALUATE
Pre_Filt


Can you share some input data ?
